# Can <meta name="theme-color"> be tested locally on a desktop?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I'm trying to test out the `<meta>` tag `<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">`, but I'd like to test this out locally on a desktop rather than somehow seeing it on a mobile device. It would be useful to see a preview of this tag in action.

This particular `<meta>` tag is outlined here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-theme-color-in-Chrome-39-for-Android

Is it possible to test this locally on a desktop? I tried going into Chrome Developer Tools and toggling the Device Toolbar, but unfortunately the mobile Chrome toolbar doesn't show up in that view.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see what browsers support this feature: 
https://caniuse.com/#search=theme-color

Currently Chrome desktop supports it if running in PWA mode.  And supposedly [you can run any webpage in this mode](https://www.addictivetips.com/web/open-a-website-as-a-stand-alone-app-in-chrome/).

On my machine, from a cmd prompt I can enter:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://cnn.com
```

But I'm not actually seeing theme colors being displayed in the title bar.